# symfony Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3. I have uploaded my website via FTP, and then I cleared the cache and the log manually. The cache and logs permissions are set to 777. Yet, I get this error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@ 
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This my `.haccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/    
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

My website is deployed to `/www/test/CrmSit/`.

The problematic path is `http://www.xxxxx.com/web/app_dev.php`

Comment: Are you sure `.haccess` is the exact file name? It should be `.htaccess` instead: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi

Comment: that's your server's generic error response, so this could be anything. Check your actual logs in /var/logs/ directory.  You'll have different logs for your prod and dev environments.  Or if you can hit your dev front controller and you have your your profiler enabled, you should be able to see the actual error.

Comment: Apache? Check httpd.conf & related conf files to see whether error documents are defined, and if the directory is correct and readable. 404 not found when accessing error docs generally means the error pages are missing or misconfigured.

Comment: kix it's .htaccess, i'm sorry but please i cannot find http.conf.

Comment: Robert Wade logs does not exist. Symfony isn't makking them

Comment: dr.nixon , i cannot find http.conf

Comment: ps -ef | grep apache  give this: XXXX  962933  933651  0 18:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache